# FancyTree has Empty Nodes

Tags: json, jquery-plugins, fancytree

I have the folowing code pretty much straight from the demo:

```
$("#treetable").fancytree({
extensions: ["table"],
table: {
indentation: 20,  // indent 20px per node level
nodeColumnIdx: 0  // render the node title into the 1st column
},
source: {url: "productTree.json"},
rendercolumns: function(e, data) {
var node = data.node,
$tdList = $(node.tr).find(">td");
// (index #0 is rendered by fancytree - see above)
$tdList.eq(1).text(node.modeldet);
$tdList.eq(2).text(node.key);
$tdList.eq(3).text(node.inclusion);
 }
});
```

And this is the JSON:

```
[
{"title": "All Products", "key": "*", "folder": true, "children": [
    {"title": "Smart Product 1", "key": "Smart", "inclusion": "Mandatory", "folder": true, "children": [
        {"title": "Simple A", "key": "One Time Fee", "modeldet": "0-50 Units"},
        {"title": "Simple B", "key": "Per Unit or Metered Usage", "modeldet": "More than 50 Units"}
    ]},
    {"title": "Simple A", "key": "One Time Fee", "inclusion": "Mandatory"},
    {"title": "Simple B", "key": "Per Unit or Metered Usage", "inclusion": "Mandatory"},
    {"title": "Simple C", "key": "Reservation", "inclusion": "Optional", "extraClasses": "my-extra-class" },
    {"title": "Simple D", "key": "Service or Recurring Fee", "inclusion": "Optional", "extraClasses": "my-extra-class" }
]}  
]
```

The tree renders but the only columns that contain data are the "title" and "key".  The others are blank.

Answer (score 0):

Most custom node data is stored in a separate namespace to avoid conflicts.
Try to access as 'node.data.modeldet' instead.